# IOS - How to fit with to parent view use autolayout

Tags: ios

I want the view with fit screen with, how to do it use autolayout in IB?

[image: demo]

Comment: There are tutorials on how to use IB and autolayout on the web. If you do an internet search you will find hundreds. For example: http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1 . Apple also provide multiple videos from WWDC that cover how to use Autolayout and the functionality it provides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select your xib/view controller and Just go to

```
Editor-> Resolve Auto Layout Issue - >Add missing constraint and update constraint
```

Thats it, your view will display proper.

Comment: worked but why get view's width is 320 and app frame width is 375 in code. NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.contentView.bounds));NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect([UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame));

Comment: What device/simulator you use for testing ?

Comment: may be your NSLog is execute in ViewDidload, Sum times this was happen because of constraint not complete till viewDidAppear so Try to write it in viewDidAppear.